# Group by Clause erroring with not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following code,

```
    Select
    pro.tariff_code as CommodityCode,
    '1000001' AS ProcedureCode,
    pro.long_description_1 as Description,
    sum(ph.weight + 0.2) as GrossWeight,
    sum(ph.weight) as NetWeight,
    sum(Si.net_price) as ItemUnitPrice,
    ed.data_text as Countryoforigin,
    sum(si.despatched_qty) as ItemQuantity,
   'PC' as Packagedcode,
   'LIC99' as Licence
from 
    package_header ph
    left join despatch_header dc on ph.despatch_num = dc.despatch_num
    left join package_product pp on ph.despatch_num = pp.despatch_num
    left join sales_header sh on pp.sales_document_num = sh.sales_document_num
    left join sales_item si on sh.sales_document_num = si.sales_document_num
    left join product pro on si.product_code = pro.product_code
    left join entity_data ed on field_name = 'CountryOfOrigin' and Entity_name = 'Product' and entity_key1 = pro.product_code
WHERE trunc(date '1970-01-01' + ph.change_date * interval '1' second) = trunc(sysdate) and sh.SALES_OFFICE = 'MSUK'
Group by pro.tariff_code, '1000001', pro.long_description_1
```

I am getting an error saying

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: I.e. try `GROUP BY pro.tariff_code, pro.long_description_1, ed.data_text` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Jarlh, works a treat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All non-aggregated columns of the `SELECT` clause must be repeated in the `group by` clause. Your code is missing `ed.data_text` in the `group by` clause - or it should be removed from the `select` clause.

```
select
    pro.tariff_code as CommodityCode,
    '1000001' AS ProcedureCode,
    pro.long_description_1 as Description,
    sum(ph.weight + 0.2) as GrossWeight,
    sum(ph.weight) as NetWeight,
    sum(Si.net_price) as ItemUnitPrice,
    ed.data_text as Countryoforigin,
    sum(si.despatched_qty) as ItemQuantity,
   'PC' as Packagedcode,
   'LIC99' as Licence
from 
    package_header ph
    left join despatch_header dc on ph.despatch_num = dc.despatch_num
    left join package_product pp on ph.despatch_num = pp.despatch_num
    left join sales_header sh on pp.sales_document_num = sh.sales_document_num
    left join sales_item si on sh.sales_document_num = si.sales_document_num
    left join product pro on si.product_code = pro.product_code
    left join entity_data ed on field_name = 'CountryOfOrigin' and Entity_name = 'Product' and entity_key1 = pro.product_code
WHERE ph.change_date >= (trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24
  AND ph.change_date <  (trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01' + 1) * 60 * 60 * 24
  AND sh.SALES_OFFICE = 'MSUK'
Group by pro.tariff_code, pro.long_description_1, ed.data_text
```

Note that I changed the filtering on the date to make it SARGeable.